# Communication link failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i'm getting this error when i'm trying to connect to mysql database

> SQLException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

please help me solve this error

This is my code to connect to database.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Unable to load Driver");
}
    Connection con = null;

try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://fdb7.biz.nf:3306/1593661_test",      "1593661_test", "thisispass");
    System.out.println("connection done.");
} catch (SQLException ex) {

System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());

}
```

help me please.

Comment: Have you check mysql server running?

Comment: yes I have checked it. it is running.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Please let me know since me also trouble.

Comment: Yes @Mohan, the database I'm  trying to connect is a remote database. And remote database access is not with the database server.